# Print only one label list java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a for loop which prints the following:

```
Data(s):
 Hospital 1
Data(s):
 Hospital 2
Data(s): 
 Hospital 3
  and continue...
```

However, I would like to have just only one label and then display all the names in separate lines.

```
Such as:
   Data(s):
    Hospital 1
    Hospital 2
    Hospital 3
  and continue...
```

Here is the Java code I have right now:

```
 for(Data data : dataList){
    Data tabData_Hospital = new Data(data);
     tabData_Hospital.setLabel("Data(s): ");
     tabDataList.add(tabData_Hospital); 
 }
```

Help appreciated..

Comment: It looks like one of your statements (presumably `tabData_Hospital.setLabel("Data(s): ");` prints the line "Data(s):". You will need to remove this from the loop

Comment: what is Data type really stands for ? where the syso instructions !!

Answer (score 1):

You need to print `"Data(s): "` before you execute the loop.

```
Data tabData_Hospital = new Data(data);
tabData_Hospital.setLabel("Data(s): ");

for(Data data : dataList){
    tabDataList.add(tabData_Hospital); 
}
```